# MySQL Use Select on Multiple Conditions on Multiple Columns in a Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with Name Database1 and Table named table1.The columns in the table are Client Name and Country.I want to search for clients based on a condition using LIKE and want to Exclude in results the Clients from NOT LIKE (NOT IN) Countries.

```
Client Name,Country

Sandeep,India

Mandeep,USA

John,Japan

Vinay,China

Amit,USA

etc...
```

I tried below stated query.It does give out results but does not filter or exclude the Not Like countries, rather displays all countries.

```
SELECT CLIENT NAME,
       COUNTRY
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1
WHERE (CLIENT NAME LIKE 'VINAY')
  OR (CLIENT NAME LIKE 'AMIT')
  AND COUNTRY NOT IN ('INDIA',
                      'JAPAN')
```

I have also tried with `NOT LIKE`:

```
SELECT CLIENT NAME,
       COUNTRY
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1
WHERE (CLIENT NAME LIKE 'VINAY')
  OR (CLIENT NAME LIKE 'AMIT')
  AND (COUNTRY NAME NOT LIKE 'INDIA')
  AND (COUNTRY NAME NOT LIKE 'JAPAN')
```

Both of above gave results But without filtering-out/excluding India and China in results.Results are appearing for all countries in-spite of using Not LIKE / NOT IN

Any Solution or what is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Change in both queires:

Query 1:

```
SELECT CLIENT NAME,
       COUNTRY
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1
WHERE (CLIENT NAME LIKE 'VINAY' OR CLIENT NAME LIKE 'AMIT')
  AND COUNTRY NOT IN ('INDIA', 'JAPAN')
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT CLIENT NAME,
       COUNTRY
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1
WHERE (CLIENT NAME LIKE 'VINAY' OR CLIENT NAME LIKE 'AMIT')
  AND COUNTRY NAME NOT LIKE 'INDIA' AND COUNTRY NAME NOT LIKE 'JAPAN'
```

Answer (score 0):

`AND` has higher [precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/operator-precedence.html) than `OR`, so your first filter is equivalent to:

```
(CLIENT NAME LIKE 'VINAY') OR (
  (CLIENT NAME LIKE 'AMIT') AND COUNTRY NOT IN ('INDIA','JAPAN')
)
```

Similarly, your second filter is equivalent to:

```
(CLIENT NAME LIKE 'VINAY') OR (
  (CLIENT NAME LIKE 'AMIT') AND
  (COUNTRY NAME NOT LIKE 'INDIA') AND
  (COUNTRY NAME NOT LIKE 'JAPAN')
)
```

To specify alternative precedence, you should include explicit parentheses:

```
(CLIENT NAME LIKE 'VINAY' OR CLIENT NAME LIKE 'AMIT')
AND COUNTRY NOT IN ('INDIA','JAPAN')
```

(Note that wrapping *individual* terms in their own parenthesis contributes nothing, so I have removed them).

Note also that your expression can be abbreviated using `IN()` for the `OR` terms:

```
CLIENT NAME IN ('VINAY','AMIT') AND COUNTRY NOT IN ('INDIA','JAPAN')
```

Comment: Resolved - Was working on the same for last 3 days....and it took 2mins for u guys to give a solution.you guys are really genius.Thanks a ton for the solution.